# Multiple terraform environments from one Git repo?

Tags: terraform, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions to deploy my code using Terraform. Whenever code is pushed to the `master` branch, a GitHub Action is triggered that builds the code and runs `terraform apply`. This works well.

The problem is that now I want to have a `staging` environment too. Whenever code is pushed to the `staging` branch, it should be built and `terraform` apply` should be run against a *different backend*.

However, this requires a different Terraform config:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "bucket-for-my-terraform-state" 
    key            = "global/s3/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "eu-west-2"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-locks"
    encrypt        = true
  }
}
```

I cannot use a Terraform variable, because those are not allowed in `backend` blocks.

How can I have multiple Terraform deployments from one Git repo with multiple branches?

---

```sh
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.14.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.23.0
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use terraform workspaces: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html. So in your master job you can 'terraform workspace select prod' and then for your staging branch use 'terraform workspace select staging'. This allows you to keep your current codebase without any changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [partial configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#partial-configuration)

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}
```

And then prepare file per each environment:

- *prod*

```
bucket         = "bucket-prod" 
key            = "global/s3/terraform.tfstate"
region         = "eu-west-2"
dynamodb_table = "terraform-locks"
encrypt        = true
```

- *staging*

```
bucket         = "bucket-staging" 
key            = "global/s3/terraform.tfstate"
region         = "eu-west-2"
dynamodb_table = "terraform-locks"
encrypt        = true
```

And then for `prod` you will call

`terraform init -backend-config=backend.prod.hcl`

and for staging it would be

`terraform init -backend-config=backend.staging.hcl`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Terraform "workspaces" is a bit of a red-herring; it does not provide complete separation of the environments.

Comment: I don't like `workspaces` either. I would prefer a different way of handling not only backend like above, but keep definition of environment separate and share just common modules.